# error: (-209) The operation is neither 'array op array'....-(Python 3.4,opencv,picamera)

Tags: arrays, opencv, python-3.4, video-processing, raspberry-pi3

I want to give an input, a video which was taken from picamera(.h264) to my python code in my PC, [as opencv-python is not getting installed in my raspbian OS].

I converted the video which was in .h264 to mp4 and gave that as input video file,and I get the below error.

```
OpenCV Error: Sizes of input arguments do not match (The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and the same number of channels), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array') in arithm_op, file /io/opencv/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp, line 659

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/ramakrishna/PycharmProjects/Lanedect/driving-lane-departure-warning-master/main.py", line 36, in <module>

    clip = clip1.fl_image(process_frame) #NOTE: it should be in BGR format

  File "/home/ramakrishna/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/moviepy/video/VideoClip.py", line 533, in fl_image

    return self.fl(lambda gf, t: image_func(gf(t)), apply_to)

  File "/home/ramakrishna/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/moviepy/Clip.py", line 136, in fl

    newclip = self.set_make_frame(lambda t: fun(self.get_frame, t))

  File "<decorator-gen-57>", line 2, in set_make_frame
 File "/home/ramakrishna/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/moviepy/decorators.py", line 14, in outplace

    f(newclip, *a, **k)

  File "/home/ramakrishna/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/moviepy/video/VideoClip.py", line 694, in set_make_frame

    self.size = self.get_frame(0).shape[:2][::-1]

  File "<decorator-gen-14>", line 2, in get_frame
  File "/home/ramakrishna/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/moviepy/decorators.py", line 89, in wrapper

    return f(*new_a, **new_kw)

  File "/home/ramakrishna/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/moviepy/Clip.py", line 95, in get_frame

    return self.make_frame(t)

  File "/home/ramakrishna/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/moviepy/Clip.py", line 136, in <lambda>

    newclip = self.set_make_frame(lambda t: fun(self.get_frame, t))

  File "/home/ramakrishna/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/moviepy/video/VideoClip.py", line 533, in <lambda>

    return self.fl(lambda gf, t: image_func(gf(t)), apply_to)

  File "/home/ramakrishna/PycharmProjects/Lanedect/driving-lane-departure-warning-master/lane.py", line 619, in process_frame

    output = create_output_frame(offcenter, pts, img_undist_, fps, curvature, curve_direction, binary_sub)

  File "/home/ramakrishna/PycharmProjects/Lanedect/driving-lane-departure-warning-master/lane.py", line 486, in create_output_frame

    output = cv2.addWeighted(undist_ori, 1, newwarp_, 0.3, 0)

cv2.error: /io/opencv/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp:659: error: (-209) The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and the same number of channels), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in function arithm_op

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Please help me solve this error.

Below are the size of input file already set in the code.But my video file size is 20.5 MB and dimensions 1920 x 1080. How can I change the dimensions if I have to?

```
left_lane = Lane()

right_lane = Lane()

frame_width = 1280

frame_height = 720

LANEWIDTH = 3.7  # highway lane width in US: 3.7 meters

input_scale = 4

output_frame_scale = 4

N = 4 # buffer previous N lines

# fullsize:1280x720

x = [194, 1117, 705, 575]

y = [719, 719, 461, 461]

X = [290, 990, 990, 290]

Y = [719, 719, 0, 0]
```

Comment: I finally changed the dimension of the video file..using Handbrake appilcation.Its working fine now.. :)